# Understanding a Transformer Blowing

Tags: power, transformer, electricity

A transformer blew around my area. For what I can tell the power did not go out in my apartment but the other complex near me, their power went out. Would a transformer blowing near my complex cause damage devices in my apartment? If a transformer blows does it always cut power to whoever is affected, so if my apartment did not lose power would it have not gotten affected by the transformer blowing?

Additionally if my apartment was affected by a blown transformer would it have tripped the circuit breaker?

Thank you for helping me to understand this I am very interested in understanding how this type of event works and had the perfect scenario to help me understand.

Does it make a difference if it is a transformer on a pole or at a station?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101488/discussion-on-question-by-j-w-understanding-a-transformer-blowing). Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).

Answer (score 1):

When a transformer blows, it interrupts electrical service, regardless of type.  Interrupted service does not control your breaker.

A transformer blows because it's internal oil insulation ignites before tripping upstream or internal over-current breakers   due to an insulation failure , not necessarily an external event such as an unprotected lightning stroke or major solar event.

Your questions seem to assume a transformer blow-up is caused by a shared external over-voltage or over-current event.

More likely it is caused by an internal insulation failure in the transformer oil insulation that was caused by the activation  or major ignition energy being exceeded with a runaway internal combustion.   These catastrophic events are minimized by best practices of routine oil sample tests and other condition-based diagnostics. **A short-circuit through detonation of combustible gasses dissolved in the oil is the predominant final cause perhaps aggravated by pyrotechnic internal temperatures.**  There can be many causes. Transformer oil is a very high quality insulator until it becomes contaminated.  The series of DGA tests below are one category of tests to measure contamination.

Here is an example of a standard oil sample test that if passed is not done until maybe a year later if values are low. But in this case within <1 yr old  was taken output service before H2 reached the 4% Lower Explosive Level dissolved in oil from PD.

[image]

In some parts of the world these tests are not done as diligently and risk of explosion on this 5 MVA transformer would be high within 1 year after these tests. In this case it was removed from service before risk was severe although PD activity was severe, that would not cause any abnormal power symptoms.

Comment: So if a transformer blew near me to affect a apartment complex near me but I did not lose power does that mean the high voltage/current did not get to my apartment? Wouldn’t my transformer That was not affected do it’s job by scaling the voltage to the appropriate voltage?